# Startup code of a statically-linked executable issues so many system calls?

Tags: c, linux, static-linking, libc, system-calls

I am experimenting by statically compiling a minimal program and examining the system calls that are issued:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  write(1, "Hello world!", 12);
  return 0;
}

$ gcc hello.c -static

$ objdump -f a.out
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x00000000004003c0

$ strace ./a.out
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="ubuntu", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xa20000
brk(0xa211a0)                           = 0xa211a0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0xa20880)       = 0
brk(0xa421a0)                           = 0xa421a0
brk(0xa43000)                           = 0xa43000
write(1, "Hello world!", 12Hello world!)            = 12
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

I know that when linked non-statically, `ld` emits startup code to map `libc.so` and `ld.so` into the process's address space, and `ld.so` would continue loading any other shared libraries.

But in this case, why are so many system calls issued, apart from `execve`, `write` and `exit_group`?

Why the heck `uname(2)`? Why so many calls to `brk(2)` to get and set the program break, and a call to `arch_prctl(2)` to set the process state, when that seems like something that should have been done in kernel-space, at `execve` time?

Comment: `brk` is roughly a low-level `malloc` so it's not that odd that it's called by the start-up code. If you're really curious why they're called why don't you break with a debugger when the relevant functions are called?

Comment: Omit the -static so it uses shared libs, then use `ltrace -S ./a.out` to see the whole bunch that's done before it finally calls your main(). While I'm typing a.out: your linux system is an older one?

Comment: @ott--, `a.out` is GCC's default output filename (when you don't pass `-o`), even on ELF systems.

Comment: @bdolan: Right, I had the executable formats in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uname` is needed to check that the kernel version is not too ancient.

Two `brk`s are needed to set up thread local storage. Two others are needed to set up dynamic loader path (the executable still might call `dlopen`, even if it's statically linked). I'm not sure why these come in pairs.

On system `arch_prctl` isn't called, `set_thread_area` is called in its place. This sets up TLS for the current thread.

These things probably could be done lazily (i.e. called when corresponding facilities are used for the first time). But perhaps it would make no sense performance-wise (just a guess).

By the way `gdb-7.x` can stop on system calls with the `catch syscall` command.

Comment: IIRC, kernel version is passed in the "auxv" vector. If so, the uname is redundant and purely a waste of cpu time.

Comment: @R isn't auxv a dynamic elf thing?

Comment: @R um, you are right, but there's no kernel version in there. Not immediately at any rate. Perhaps it's hidden somewhere in AT_SYSINFO or somesuch, but not all kernels pass that. It's more reliable to just call `uname`.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I suppose if you're just testing for a "new enough" version (e.g. for NPTL) you might be able to use the presence of a particular AT_* entry, but otherwise `uname` might really be needed...

Answer (score 6):

Shameless plug: When built against musl libc, the strace for that program static linked *or dynamic linked* is:

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
write(1, "Hello world!", 12)            = 12
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

It should be similarly minimal with dietlibc if you static link, or with uClibc and static linking as long as you built uClibc with locale and advanced stdio stuff disabled. (For some reason uClibc with those features enabled runs lots of startup code to initialize them even in programs that don't use them...). As far as I know, however, musl is the only one that has a dynamic linker capable of avoiding heavy startup syscall overhead in dynamic-linked programs.

As for *why* static linking with glibc makes all those `brk` calls, I really have no idea; you'd have to read the source. I suspect it's allocating space for internal data structures for `malloc`, stdio, locale, and possibly the thread structure for the main thread. As n.m. said, the `arch_prctl` is for setting the thread register to point to the main thread's thread structure. This *could* be deferred to the first access (which musl does), but it's a bit of a pain to do so and mildly hurts performance. If you care about the runtime of large programs more than the startup time of many many small programs, it may make sense to always initialize the thread register at program load time. Note that the kernel cannot set it for you because it does not know the address it should be set to.

It's possible that an extension to the ELF format could be made to allow the main thread structure to be in the `.data` section with an ELF header telling the kernel where it is, but the acrobatics needed between the libc, the linker, and the kernel would probably be so ugly as to make this optimization undesirable... They would also impose further constraints on the userspace implementation of threads.